# How may I unit-test hardware-based-licensed code in the Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops

I'm trying to automate the building and testing of several projects for several repos in an Azure DevOps project.  The build part seems easy but my functions to be unit tested require an installed, hardware-tied license that obviously I never generated for the transient virtual machine running the tests.   So after my build completes and the tests try to run, they'll fail with a licensing error

I can't be the first person to deal with an issue like this.  Is there a standard, common way to work around this hardware-based licensing issues when testing a build in a cloud environment like Azure DevOps?

(We needed a hardware tied license because clients running the code must work in disconnected scenarios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How may I unit-test hardware-based-licensed code in the Azure DevOps pipeline?

I am afraid there is no such out of way to use hardware-tied license with cloud environment at this moment.

To resolve this issue, you could create your private agent to tied hardware tied license:

[How to Set Up a Private Agent in Visual Studio Team Services](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-set-up-a-private-agent-in-visual-studio-tea)

Comment: Thank you, Leo.  I saw a reference to private agents in the PluralSight course I've been watching.  I may go that route.

However, one other possible solution occurred to me last night:  We have the ability to issue *temporary* license files that work on any machine.   So would it be possible for me to use the private storage in Azure Devops Pipelines to store such a license file (like one good for a full year) and then incorporate "installing" that file into the build?  "Installing" the file just means  copying it to the shared Windows directory where the code expects it